# Can withers be created in a mushroom biome?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm currently playing Minecraft on a factions server where raiding is a pretty common occurrence. Obsidian is an effective defense against tnt and creepers, but a wither can still get through it. Would building my next obsidian base in a mushroom biome force enemy players to spawn a wither far away and lure it to my base, or can one be built in a mushroom biome?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, when it comes to this kind of questions, the best way is to try...

[image: Wither on Mushroom Island]

And the answer is **yes**.

P.S. No mooshrooms were harmed when conducting this experiment.

Comment: `No mooshrooms were harmed` - I don't believe you...

Comment: @fredley I quit and deleted the world before the Wither's health bar is full. Unless you count deleting world as harming them...

Comment: @AlvinWong You monster!

Comment: @AlvinWong idiot.

Answer (score 0):

Withers can be built anywhere. The [only things to observe](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wither#Spawning) is that the last block cannot be placed in soul sand and that it cannot be assembled by pistons.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, yes you can build withers in the mooshroom biome.

Comment: Sadly? Why sadly?

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You can make withers anywhere.

Comment: how is this different from the other answer?

Comment: Welcome to the site @Gamehacker19, as good practice, you should not supply a duplicate answer to an already answered question, unless your answer contains more detail (testing, links to information, photos)